# Collapsable code in gedit

Tags: linux, editor, gedit

How to collapse a function , class , or method in gedit.
i managed to install all plugins for gedit , but unable to find any plugin for the same.

Answer (score 9):

In gedit 3 I am currently am using my own fork of the plugin others have mentioned. It is not perfect, but it works fairly well for me anyway. https://github.com/aeischeid/gedit-folding

Answer (score 1):

I just found this updated version of gedit-folding:
http://code.google.com/p/gedit-folding/issues/detail?id=4

Just download `folding.py` and `folding.gedit-plugin` and save them to `~/.local/share/gedit/plugins` then enable "Simple Folding" under Edit>Preferences>Plugins.

To use, move to *the very beginning* of a block and press Alt+Z.
I've given it a quick test with Python, Javascript and HTML files and it seemed to collapse most blocks, with the notable exception of multiline strings and comments.

It isn't perfect, but it's better than nothing, I guess.

**Update:** I've just tested it with badly indented code. The folding seems to be based on indentation only.

Answer (score 0):

for ubuntu 10.04 works this folding plugin:

http://code.google.com/p/gedit-folding/downloads/list

install it for the user by placing it at

```
~/.gnome2/gedit/plugins/
```

or for the system

```
/usr/lib/gedit-2/plugins/
```

Comment: so , what is the alternative

Comment: the plugin is not jet been ported for gedit3 so there is no one